# How to add an optional string extension?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

You can create a String extension like so:

```
extension String {
   func someFunc() -> Bool { return true }
}
```

but what if you want it to apply to optional string?

```
var optionalString: String? = ""
optionalString!.someFunc() /* String? does not have a member someFunc */
```

Attempting to add `extension String? {` produces the error:

> Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Optional' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause

Comment: You need to unwrap it always to apply an extension

Comment: So I unwrapped it, but maybe I did that wrong? `optionalString!.someFunc()`

Comment: If you are sure optional won't return nil that's ok otherwise you need to use if let

Comment: It will sometimes be nil, that's why optional is used.  I'm still debugging, I suspect my Playground is just out of sync.  I may close this question in a second.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus yes, that's what i was hoping to put in the extension and use the extension to solve.  I don't like the nested IF-statements.  My guess is eventually a future version of Swift will improve on this

Comment: I think you should take a look at the "??" nil coalescing operator to return an empty string "" instead of nil

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus that sounds promising.  It's been many months since I've read the Swift guide — just now getting back into it.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

In Swift 3.1 you can add an extension to optional values as well:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
  var isBlank: Bool {
    return self?.isBlank ?? true
  }
}
```

Comment: What does its usage look like?

Comment: `if myOptionalString?.isBlank {` gives value of optional type Bool? not unwrapped still.

Comment: And getting a `Type Wrapped constrained to non-protocol type String` error as well.

[Here's a probably relevant discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/42wf8m/is_there_a_way_to_write_extension_for_specific/) looks like this may be fixed in the future.

Comment: Is it possible to do this `where Wrapped == T`?

Comment: Usage is `myOptionalString.isBlank`. Without the `?` since you're calling it on the optional itself instead of on the `String`.

Comment: this is giving error in swift 4.1 "'Optional' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context"

Comment: Another usage might be adding a label string to an optional enum. Instead of using nil-coalescing for the `nil` case, now you can provide the string value in a normal switch-case. This is helpful for Picker-like UI with an optional enum as data source.

Answer (score 15):

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var isNil: Bool {
        return self == nil
    }
}
```

The above answer written by @Vlad Hatko works fine, but in Swift 4 there are some issues so I changed it to this.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it like this:

```
protocol OptionalType { typealias A; var opt: A? { get } }
extension Optional: OptionalType { var opt: A? { return self } }

protocol StringType { var get: String { get } }
extension String: StringType { var get: String { return self } }

extension Optional where Wrapped: StringType {
  func getOrElse(s: String) -> String {
    return self.opt?.get ?? s
  }
}
```

And:

```
let optStr: String? = nil
optStr.getOrElse("hello world")
```

The reason that you cannot constrain `Optional` or `String` for that matter, is because they are `struct`. By making pseudo-protocol for each, now we can constrain as we like.

I feel like swift has given up a lot of things just to make it **easier** for beginners to learn or maybe the language hasn't matured enough yet.

Comment: Is this new? I thought I tried to extend the optional type in the past

Comment: @vol7ron This is now possible with protocol extension that came with swift 2.

Answer (score 13):

## Extensions on `Optional` that return a `String`

As of Swift 3, you cannot directly constrain an extension method to an optional `String`. You can achieve the equivalent result with protocols as Daniel Shin's answer explains.

You can however, create an extension method on an Optional of any type and I've found some useful methods that have a `String` return value. These extensions are helpful for logging values to the console. I've used asStringOrEmpty() on a `String` optional when I want to replace a possible nil with empty string.

```
extension Optional {
    func asStringOrEmpty() -> String {
        switch self {
            case .some(let value):
                return String(describing: value)
            case _:
                return ""
        }
    }

    func asStringOrNilText() -> String {
        switch self {
            case .some(let value):
                return String(describing: value)
            case _:
                return "(nil)"
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use:**

```
var booleanValue: Bool?
var stringValue: String?
var intValue: Int?

print("booleanValue: \(booleanValue.asStringOrNilText())")
print("stringValue: \(stringValue.asStringOrNilText())")
print("intValue: \(intValue.asStringOrNilText())")

booleanValue = true
stringValue = "text!"
intValue = 41

print("booleanValue: \(booleanValue.asStringOrNilText())")
print("stringValue: \(stringValue.asStringOrNilText())")
print("intValue: \(intValue.asStringOrNilText())")
```

**Console Output:**

```
booleanValue: (nil)
stringValue: (nil)
intValue: (nil)

booleanValue: true
stringValue: text!
intValue: 41
```

### `Optional` different than nil pointer

These extensions illustrate that an `Optional` is different that a nil pointer. An `Optional` is a `enum` of a specified type (`Wrapped`) which indicates that it does or does not contain a value. You can write an extension on the `Optional` "container" even though it may not contain a value.

**Excerpt from Swift Optional Declaration**

```
enum Optional<Wrapped> : ExpressibleByNilLiteral {

    /// The absence of a value.
    case none

    /// The presence of a value, stored as `Wrapped`.
    case some(Wrapped)

    ...
}
```

In code, the absence of a value is typically written using the `nil` literal rather than the explicit `.none` enumeration case.

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 4.1 I was getting a `Optional is ambiguous for type lookup in this context` build error.  To fix, you have to explicitly add the Swift namespace to the type:

```swift
extension Swift.Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var isBlank: Bool {
        return self?.isBlank ?? true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Xcode 9.3, you can use this slight modification of @Vladyslav's answer:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {

    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return self?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** For a workaround that works with Swift 2 and above, see [Daniel Shin’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33717847/429427)

---

An optional String isn't in and of itself a type, and so you cannot create an extension on an optional type. In Swift, an `Optional` is just an enum (plus a bit of syntactic sugar) which can either be `None`, or `Some` that wraps a value. To use your String method, you need to unwrap your `optionalString`. You can easily use optional chaining to achieve this:

```
optionalString?.someFunc()
```

If `optionalString` is not `nil`, `someFunc` will be called on it. An alternative (less concise) way of doing this is to use optional binding to establish whether or not `optionalString` has a value before trying to call the method:

```
if let string = optionalString {
    string.someFunc()    // `string` is now of type `String` (not `String?`)
}
```

---

In your example from the comments below, you needn't nest multiple `if` statements, you can check if the optional string is an empty string in a single `if`:

```
if optionalString?.isEmpty == true {
    doSomething()
}
```

This works because the expression `optionalString?.isEmpty` returns an optional Bool (i.e. `true`, `false` or `nil`). So `doSomething()` will only be called if `optionalString` is *not* `nil`, *and* if that string is empty.

Another alternative would be:

```
if let string = optionalString where string.isEmpty {
    doSomethingWithEmptyString(string)
}
```

Comment: I was trying to create an extension to avoid optional binding.  It seems like that won't be possible

Comment: @vol7ron Can I ask why? Is the optional chaining/binding inconvenient somehow?

Comment: Consider an optional string that you want to check if it contains a character.  To my knowledge, you have to use nested if's `if let str=optString { if str.isEmpty { doSomething(); } }` I'd rather this be an `isBlank` extension of an optional string

Comment: My example (in comment) wasn't complete, but *isBlank* is generally *nil* or *isEmpty* results to true.

Comment: Right, you're coming up with ways which are not nearly as readable as other languages.  `if optStr.isBlank { … }` boom.  For something as new as Swift, you would think the end goal would be to be readable because readable is maintainable.

Comment: I could continue to suggest alternatives (a top level `func isBlank(string: String?) -> Bool` springs to mind, to take the functional approach), but ultimately you can't do exactly what you're asking. Swift doesn't currently allow extensions on generics, otherwise you could extend ` Optional<String>`, but perhaps we will be able to in the future - I'd recommend filing a feature request.

Comment: I think it's a matter of getting used to the syntax of the language - obviously, every language is different. Swift and its mechanism for optionals allows for compile time type safety and prevents values from unexpectedly being nil, but in exchange you are required to be explicit about handling cases where a value _might_ be nil. For me, it's a trade-off I'm happy enough to work with. I'm sure readability was one goal of the development of Swift, but I think safety was even more important.

Comment: But if you've built that safety into an extension, you solve both cases.  Functions written for the expressed condition of handling nil and non-nil allows you to detach the logic from the flow of the rest of the code.

Comment: @Stuart Your answer is out of date. You can indeed create an extension for a specific optional type. See Daniel Shin's answer below for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33717847/39155

Answer (score 2):

You can create an optional string extension. I did the following to set an optional string to empty if it was nil :

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {

    mutating func setToEmptyIfNil() {
        guard self != nil else {
            self = ""
            return
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

found some trick swift 3

```
class A{
    var name:String!;
    init(_ name:String?){
        self.name = name;
    }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    func compareText(_ other:String?)->Bool{
        switch (self,other){
        case let(a?,b?):
            return a < b;
        case (nil,_):
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}

let words:[A] = [A("a"),A(nil),A("b"),A("c"),A(nil)];

// let sorted = words.sorted{ 0.name.compareText($1.name) }
// trick
let sorted = words.sorted{ ($0.name as String?).compareText($1.name) }

print(sorted.map{$0.name});
```